# Does nodejs pause reading file from hard drive while the fs.ReadStream is paused?

Tags: node.js, stream, fs

Does anybody know, what is hapenning, when fs.ReadStream is paused? Does the reading of the file continue and content is buffered in background (so much memory is taken), or it is clever and doesn't read rest of the file from hard drive until the read stream is resumed?

Thanks for answer!

Comment: What do you mean by "paused"

Comment: read streams implements method "pause()" (when 'data' listeners are used), so no data are firet to the callback (or when all pipes are unpiped)
see https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pause

Comment: This is easy to find out via reading the source code or simply keeping an eye on system resources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NodeJS is clever enough to pause reading file from a hard drive too while readstream is paused.

(Tested by running testing script and watching system resources, thanks for suggestion raam86).

Comment: Debugging is healthy. gj